# Error building Android package in Unreal Engine 4.27.2

Tags: android, unreal-engine4

I am encountering an error while attempting to build an Android package in Unreal Engine 4.27.2. The specific error message I found in logs:

```
Execution failed for task ':app:bundleReleaseResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
> AAPT2 aapt2-4.0.0-6051327-windows Daemon #0: Unexpected error during link, attempting to stop daemon.
This should not happen under normal circumstances, please file an issue if it does.
```

I tried removing everything and installed again but still same issue

Comment: I solved this issue by myself , As i am using unreal engine 4 so i've installed API levels below 30 i.e 29,28,25 and in sdk build tools 29.0.3,29.0.2,28.0.3 and in ndk 21.1 and 21.4.
Also try to Remove intermediate folder and run setupandroid batch file before packaging.
Hope this may help you.